# How to find out where alias (in the bash sense) is defined when running Terminal in Mac OS X

Tags: terminal, alias, bash

How can I find out where an alias is defined on my system?  I am referring to the kind of alias that is used within a Terminal session launched from Mac OS X (10.6.3).

For example, if I enter the `alias` command with no parameters at a Terminal command prompt, I get a list of aliases that I have set, for example:

```
alias mysql='/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql'
```

However, I have searched all over my system using Spotlight and `mdfind` in various startup files and so far can not find where this alias has been defined. ( I did it a long time ago and didn't write down where I assigned the alias).

Comment: This question is (now) off-topic for StackOverflow, and it was answered [on Unix&Linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38330/how-can-i-find-a-rogue-alias-declaration).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to U&L (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38330/how-can-i-find-a-rogue-alias-declaration) or SuperUser.

Answer (score 77):

For OSX, this 2-step sequence worked well for me, in locating an alias I'd created long ago and couldn't locate in expected place (~/.zshrc).

```
cweekly:~ $ which la
la: aliased to ls -lAh

cweekly:~$ grep -r ' ls -lAh' ~
/Users/cweekly//.oh-my-zsh/lib/aliases.zsh:alias la='ls -lAh'
```

Aha! "Hiding" in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/aliases.zsh`. I had poked around a bit in .oh-my-zsh but had overlooked lib/aliases.zsh.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: This is brute force but effective and doesn't require any guesswork. Seems like the easiest way to go.

Comment: You might get `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin` and it could take some time to run this

Comment: @lacostenycoder you may have omitted the `~` argument at the end of the command, without it grep will wait to parse any input rather than searching across files locally.

Comment: This actually the exact alias I was looking for, with the same culprit Oh-my-zsh. Thanks

Comment: Just as @Brenwell said, this is exactly why I was searching for an answer to this!!

Comment: FWIW, this `ls -lAh` alias looks to be in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh` now.

Answer (score 38):

you can just simply type in `alias` on the command prompt to see what aliases you have. Otherwise, you can do a `find` on the most common places where aliases are defined, eg

```
grep -RHi "alias" /etc /root
```

Comment: Options: `-R, -r, --recursive`: Recursively search subdirectories listed, `-H`:      Always print filename headers with output lines, `-i, --ignore-case`: Perform case insensitive matching.  By default, grep is case sensitive.

Answer (score 30):

## First use the following commands

#### List all functions

```
functions
```

#### List all aliases

```
alias
```

#### If you aren't finding the alias or function consider a more aggressive searching method

## Bash version

```
bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep thingToSearchHere
```

## Zsh version

```
zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep thingToSearchHere
```

## Brief Explanation of Options

```
-i     Force shell to be interactive.

-c     Take the first argument as a command to execute

-x      -- equivalent to --xtrace

-l      Make bash act as if invoked as a login shell
```

Comment: What does `:` after `-ixc` mean, is it a command to be executed? Thanks!

Comment: `:` is a shell builtin that is basically equivalent to the true command. Historically, Bourne shells didn't have true and false as built-in commands.

Comment: @Chad see above

Comment: This is great! For me trying to find which file in zsh I did `zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | ag $pattern | grep '/' | grep alias:` after defining my pattern string `pattern=someLongThing`

Comment: Always appreciate it when someone appreciates the help (tips hat)

Answer (score 19):

Also in future these are the standard bash config files

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_logout
- ~/.bashrc

*More info: http://www.heimhardt.com/htdocs/bashrcs.html*

Comment: `/etc/bashrc` is also be looked at.

Comment: On some machines `/etc/bashrc` may be named `/etc/bash.bashrc`. It is on my Debian 7 machine anyway.

Comment: In addition, some distros put system wide settings in `/etc/bash/`.

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to the party, but I was having the same problem (trying to find where the "l." command was aliased in RHEL6), and ended up in a place not mentioned in the previous answers.  It may not be found in all bash implementations, but if the /etc/profile.d/ directory exists, try grepping there for unexplained aliases.  That's where I found:

```
[user@server ~]$ grep l\\. /etc/profile.d/*
/etc/profile.d/colorls.csh:alias l. 'ls -d .*'
/etc/profile.d/colorls.csh:alias l. 'ls -d .* --color=auto'
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh:  alias l.='ls -d .*' 2>/dev/null
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh:alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto' 2>/dev/null
```

The directory isn't mentioned in the bash manpage, and isn't properly part of where bash searches for profile/startup info, but in the case of RHEL you can see the calling code within /etc/profile:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
  if [ -r "$i" ]; then
    if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
      . "$i"
    else
      . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

**Please do check custom installations/addons/plugins you have added, in addition to the .zshrc/.bashrc/.profile etc files**

So for me: it was git aliased to 'g'.

```
$ which g
g: aliased to git
```

Then I ran the following command to list all aliases

```
$ alias
```

I found a whole lot of git related aliases that I knew I had not manually added.
This got me thinking about packages or configurations I had installed. And so went to the

> .oh-my-zsh
> directory. Here I ran the following command:

```
$ grep -r 'git' . |grep -i alias
```

And lo and behold, I found my alias in :

> ./plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer ( I had been staring at the correct file but missed the obvious ).

The aliases in my case are defined in the file ~/.bash_profile

Somehow this eluded me.

Comment: thank you, tried .bashrc and .bash_aliases, forgot it was .bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

For more complex setups (e.g. when you're using a shell script framework like bash-it, oh-my-zsh or the likes) it's often useful to add 'alias mysql' at key positions in your scripts. This will help you figure out exactly when the alias is added.

e.g.:

```
echo "before sourcing .bash-it:"
alias mysql
. $HOME/.bash-it/bash-it.sh
echo "after sourcing bash:"
alias mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe this is similar to what [ghostdog74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614403/how-to-find-out-where-alias-in-the-bash-sense-is-defined-when-running-terminal/2615453#2615453) meant however their command didn't work for me.

I would try something like this:

```
for i in `find . -type f`; do   # find all files in/under current dir
echo "========" 
echo $i                         # print file name
cat $i | grep "alias"           # find if it has alias and if it does print the line containing it
done
```

If you wanted to be really fancy you could even add an `if [[ grep -c "alias" ]] then <print file name>`

Comment: Rather than loop, backtick, find, echo, and cat, a simple `grep -R alias .` will do what you suggest.  The crux of the question however is *where to look*.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way of finding where the alias could have been defined is by analyzing the list of files opened by `bash` using [dtruss](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dtruss/).

If

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
```

you won't be able to open `bash` and you may need a copy.

```
$ cp /bin/bash mybash
$ $ codesign --remove-signature mybash
```

and then use

```
sudo dtruss -t open ./mybash -ic exit 2>&1 | awk -F'"' '/^open/ {print substr($2, 0, length($2)-2)}'
```

to list all the files where the `alias` could have been defined, like

```
/dev/dtracehelper
/dev/tty
/usr/share/locale/en_CA.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/BASH.mo
/usr/share/locale/en_CA.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/BASH.mo
/usr/share/locale/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/BASH.mo
/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/BASH.mo
/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/BASH.mo
/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/BASH.mo
/Users/user/.bashrc
/Users/user/.bash_aliases
/Users/user/.bash_history
...
```

Answer (score -5):

Try: `alias | grep name_of_alias`
Ex.: `alias | grep mysql`

or, as already mentioned above

`which name_of_alias`

Answer (score -8):

In my case, I use Oh My Zsh, so I put aliases definition in **~/.zshrc** file.

Comment: Posted with more detail two and a half years ago.

Comment: The question is that he can't remember where aliases are defined in Mac OSX which I had run into, so I just give the file location(~/.zshrc) that worked for me(I use Oh My Zsh). I really don't know what do you mean about more detail.

Comment: I mean, an [existing answer from Nov 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614403/how-to-find-out-where-alias-in-the-bash-sense-is-defined-when-running-terminal/43245187#26742455) already said everything in this answer and added more as well.