# I have a custom alias for `ls -als` called `la` in my zshrc, and it's being overwritten by something as `ls -lAh`. Where is this coming from?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I have the following in my `.zshrc`

```
alias la="ls -als"
```

And it's being overwritten

```
▶︎ which la
la: aliased to ls -lAh
```

Why is this happening / where might it be coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helped largely by https://stackoverflow.com/a/26742455/413254, it turns out that oh-my-zsh has some built in directory aliases in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh` one of which overwrote my custom one!

```
▶︎ cat directories.zsh
# Changing/making/removing directory
...
# List directory contents
alias lsa='ls -lah'
alias l='ls -lah'
alias ll='ls -lh'
alias la='ls -lAh'
```

You could resolve this in a few ways:

- Change my `la` alias to something else
- Modify the above `.oh-my-zsh` file
- Make sure that I'm defining my alias AFTER `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` in my `.zshrc`. That `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` sources basically everything in `.oh-my-zsh/lib`

I went with the last option.

Comment: Right; assume that `oh-my-zsh.sh` can or will override anything you do yourself, and only do things before sourcing that file that are intended to *affect* that file.

Comment: (Or option 4: don't use `oh-my-zsh.sh` directly, instead cherry-picking the bits you find interesting and putting them in your configuration files directly.)